How fix ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence?
I was looking at the code for implementing Q-learning algorithm in gymnasium Pendulum-v1 environment and came across a github with a similar implementation, but when I try to run the code I get an error: "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous part." I don't know how to solve it and would welcome any help.
Full Code:
import os
import gym
import pickle
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

env = gym.make("Pendulum-v1")

ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
LOAD_PRETRAINED = True
VALIDATING = True
LEARNING_RATE = 0.1
DISCOUNT = 0.95
EPISODES = 150000
SHOW_EVERY = 10000
STATS_EVERY = 100
epsilon = 1
EPSILON_THRESHOLD = 0.1
epsilon_decay_value = 0.99999

# Making discrete action space
DISCRETE_ACTION_SPACE_SIZE = 17
discrete_action_space_win_size = (env.action_space.high - env.action_space.low) / (DISCRETE_ACTION_SPACE_SIZE - 1)
action_space = {}
for i in range(DISCRETE_ACTION_SPACE_SIZE):
    action_space[i] = [env.action_space.low[0] + (i * discrete_action_space_win_size[0])]

# # Making discrete observation space
DISCRETE_OS_SIZE = [21, 21, 65]
discrete_os_win_size = (env.observation_space.high - env.observation_space.low) / [i - 1 for i in DISCRETE_OS_SIZE]
if LOAD_PRETRAINED:
    q1_table = np.load(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'q1table.npy')))
    q2_table = np.load(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'q2table.npy')))
else:
    q1_table = np.random.uniform(low = -2, high = -0, size = (DISCRETE_OS_SIZE + [DISCRETE_ACTION_SPACE_SIZE]))
    q2_table = np.random.uniform(low = -2, high = -0, size = (DISCRETE_OS_SIZE + [DISCRETE_ACTION_SPACE_SIZE]))
ep_rewards = []
aggr_ep_rewards = {'ep': [], 'avg': [], 'max': [], 'min': []}


def get_discrete_state(state):
    ds = (state - env.observation_space.low) / discrete_os_win_size
    return tuple(ds.astype(np.int32))


if VALIDATING:
    epsilon = 0
    SHOW_EVERY = 1


def maxAction(state):
    values = np.add(q1_table[state], q2_table[state])
    action = np.argmax(values)
    return action


for episode in range(EPISODES):
    episode_reward = 0
    discrete_state = get_discrete_state(env.reset())
    done = False

    if episode % SHOW_EVERY == 0:
        render = True
    else:
        render = False
    while not done:
        if np.random.random() > epsilon:
            # Get action from Q tables
            action = maxAction(discrete_state)
        else:
            # Get random action
            action = np.random.randint(0, DISCRETE_ACTION_SPACE_SIZE)
        torque = action_space[action]
        new_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(torque)
        episode_reward += reward
        new_discrete_state = get_discrete_state(new_state)
        if episode % SHOW_EVERY == 0:
            env.render()
        if not VALIDATING:
            if not done:
                if np.random.random() <= 0.5:
                    action_ = np.argmax(q1_table[new_discrete_state])
                    # And here's our equation for a new Q value for current state and action
                    new_q = (1 - LEARNING_RATE) * q1_table[discrete_state + (action,)] + LEARNING_RATE * (
                                reward + DISCOUNT * q2_table[new_discrete_state + (action_,)])
                    # Update Q table with new Q value
                    q1_table[discrete_state + (action,)] = new_q

                else:
                    action_ = np.argmax(q2_table[new_discrete_state])
                    # And here's our equation for a new Q value for current state and action
                    new_q = (1 - LEARNING_RATE) * q2_table[discrete_state + (action,)] + LEARNING_RATE * (
                            reward + DISCOUNT * q1_table[new_discrete_state + (action_,)])
                    # Update Q table with new Q value
                    q2_table[discrete_state + (action,)] = new_q

            if new_state[0] == 0 and new_state[1] == 1:
                q1_table[discrete_state + (action,)] = 0
                q2_table[discrete_state + (action,)] = 0
                print(f"Acheived in {episode}")

        discrete_state = new_discrete_state
    if not VALIDATING:
        # Decaying is being done every episode if episode number is within decaying range
        if epsilon >= EPSILON_THRESHOLD:
            epsilon *= epsilon_decay_value
        ep_rewards.append(episode_reward)
        if not episode % STATS_EVERY:
            average_reward = sum(ep_rewards[-STATS_EVERY:]) / STATS_EVERY
            aggr_ep_rewards['ep'].append(episode)
            aggr_ep_rewards['avg'].append(average_reward)
            aggr_ep_rewards['max'].append(max(ep_rewards[-STATS_EVERY:]))
            aggr_ep_rewards['min'].append(min(ep_rewards[-STATS_EVERY:]))
            print(f'Episode: {episode:>5d}, average reward: {average_reward:>4.1f}, current epsilon: {epsilon:>1.2f}')
        if episode % 10 == 0:
            np.save(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'q1table.npy')), q1_table)
            np.save(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'q2table.npy')), q2_table)

env.close()

if not VALIDATING:
    filehandler = open("statistics", 'wb')
    pickle.dump(aggr_ep_rewards, filehandler)

    plt.plot(aggr_ep_rewards['ep'], aggr_ep_rewards['avg'], label = "average rewards")
    plt.plot(aggr_ep_rewards['ep'], aggr_ep_rewards['max'], label = "max rewards")
    plt.plot(aggr_ep_rewards['ep'], aggr_ep_rewards['min'], label = "min rewards")
    plt.legend(loc = 4)
    plt.savefig(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "Statistics.png")))
    plt.show()

Error:  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Q-Learning_and_Double-Q-Learning-main\\Double-Q-Learning\\Pendulum-Double-qlearning.py", line 59, in \<module\>
discrete_state = get_discrete_state(env.reset())
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Q-Learning_and_Double-Q-Learning-main\\Double-Q-Learning\\Pendulum-Double-qlearning.py", line 42, in get_discrete_state
ds = (state - env.observation_space.low) / discrete_os_win_size
\~\~\~\~\~\~^\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous part.


Have you tested or developed this piece by piece?  Or is this code borrowed without much understanding?  You are trying to make an array from something with mixed sizes - what used to called a 'rugged array'.  You fix it by identifying the 'rugged' stuff and correcting the shapes!

My guess is that you'll have to pay more attention to what gym produces.  That's not something we can help you with.
